# Form closing automatically after it's been opened for sometime with CloseReason.None

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, debugging

I'm having a very strange issue with my Winforms Application. After my application has been opened for say 6,7 hours, it keeps closing on its own. The application is doing heavy and convoluted work related to Serial Communication, Constant DB Upsert with multithreading.

Several methods I've tried are:

- Catching top-level exception on main method and thread exceptions. No exceptions occur.
- Handling Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event. Again, no event occurs.
- Handle FormClosing event to look at Form.CloseReason. It returns as CloseReason.None, which isn't really helpful

The problem is that I cannot reproduce this issue on every instance and it takes an awful amount of time to even get to this issue. At the moment, I'm just returning immediately in my form closing event if the close reason is none, but this feels like a ticking timebomb to me.

What are some general debugging techniques I can employ to catch issues like this?

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer of windows?

Comment: @RonaldEstacion No, that thought hasn't crossed my mind. Which events in particular should I be looking at?

Comment: You probably need to check the Event Viewer>Windows Logs>Application path to check the events that occured after your app closed, try checking for the previous ones if not just replicate it again.

Comment: I might help to add logging to your app.   "Entering functionA"  "Leaving functionA" "Pre save to database"  "Post save to databse".   When you get it narrowed down, add more detailed logging to the section where it occurs.

Comment: What about dumping the callstack (`System.Environment.StackTrace`) to a text file when `FormClosing` occurs with a `CloseReason` of none?

Comment: If you're currently using a Release build (which I doubt, but just to be sure), then switch to a Debug build. Have vague recollections of experiencing something similar years and years ago, it turned out to be misuse of a Window handle from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Does the window opened with Show() or ShowDialog()?